# How to create a command line application like awscli with python in windows?

Tags: python, windows, command-line-interface

I would like to create an application running from CLI in windows like the awscli program.

It should be built with python script and when running that it showld perform soma action like

```
samplepgm login -u akhil -p raju
```

Like this, Could you guide me in creating this kind of cli application in Windows with python.

Comment: Have you already read the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: I recommend [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) :)

Comment: I need an executable and I would like to run like `samplepgm login -u akhil -p raju` is there any samples or tutorials for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have implemented this using [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which will build an exe file of the python files. Will work with all versions of Python

First you need to create your python cli script for the task, then build the exe using

`pyinstaller --onefile -c -F -n Cli-latest action.py`

If you need to get inputs from users then you can do a infinite loop which will request for `input`

(Try `input("My Dev:-$ "`)

Comment: The pyinstaller doesn't answer your question, it's only a package bundle.

Assuming this answer as the correct is not good for people who are looking for how to create a CLI tool.

Comment: @eliocapelati I have mentioned that I implemented using Pyinstaller package, and using that I created the exe file which will be executable in Windows

Answer (score 1):

Check out `argparse` for something basic: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

For a better library check out `Click`:
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

Others:

- https://pypi.org/project/argh/
- http://docopt.org/

Comment: How to make that executable from windows like `samplepgm login -u akhil -p raju`

Comment: Once you've written your script, you can package it as an exe: http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: The two solutions are independent, by the way. Any of those solutions should work with py2exe